password authentication failed for user "postgres" in lightdash
I'm trying to create a new Lightdash project. I used the Lightdash CLI to set up the project locally. After configuring the PostgreSQL and dbt connections, I was able to successfully test and compile the setup. However, when I attempt to run a query, I encounter the following error:

Password authentication failed for user 'postgres'.




In the first screenshot ,it is actually not checking the database connection. If you’re running PostgreSQL locally, but your configuration is expecting a remote connection, it could be an issue

Are you running either/both lightdash and postgres in docker containers?

It might be worth cross-posting in Lightdash's slack community too: https://join.slack.com/t/lightdash-community/shared_invite/zt-2v5o9s6n5-tdB7TGr3mXQbbgtb18lIMw

It would be helpful to see the uncommented lines in your pg_hba.conf to ensure you have actually configured postresql to allow the access you think the gui has configured for you. I strongly favor manual config instead of relying on some "tool" to get it right.

@samhita  I tried using remote connection ,the configuration and database creditial is correct but still getting same issues
